# Computing terms x terms matrix

Tags: java, loops, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am stuck on a problem for a very long time which requires me to compute a terms x terms matrix. So, I have 2 arrays which is **keywords** and **sentences** as below:

```
String[] Keywords = {"Human", "Machine", "Interface", "Application" };
String[] Sentence = {"Human is Machine", "Interface of Robot", "Application on Human"};
```

Next, I have to tabulate them as shown in the figure below.

[image: Result in 2D array]

**Logic:**

1. We put a 0 if the row and column is of the same keyword.
2. In Human(row) x Machine(column) space, we put 1 because these two
   words appear in the same sentence once (that is the first sentence
   in the array).
3. In Human(row) x Interface(column), we put 0 because this two words
   doesn't exist together in neither of the sentences.
4. The search is non case sensitive.
5. And proceed to the next column and then next row.

This is what I've attempted but somehow something is wrong.

```
    public class Test {

    public static  int [][] matrix;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] Keywords = {"Human", "Machine", "Interface", "Application" };
        String[] Sentence = {"Human is Machine", "Interface of Robot", "Application on Human"};

         int [][] matrix = new int[Keywords.length][Keywords.length];   //initialize matrix

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Keywords));
            System.out.println("\n"+ Arrays.toString(Sentence));



            for (int i=0;i<Keywords.length;i++)
            {
                int count = 0;
                for (int q=1;q<Sentence.length;q++)
                {
                    if (Keywords[i].contains(Sentence[q]))
                    {
                        matrix[i][q] = count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));




    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some logical errors in your `for`loop.
With `if (Keywords[i].contains(Sentence[q]))` you are checking whether the keyword contains the sentence and not whether the opposite holds.
Another thing is that your matrix is based on the `Keywords` yet you are using the `Sentence` iterator to indicate the line.
Correct code would be

```
for (int i=0;i<Keywords.length-1;i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j < Keywords.length; j++){
        int count = 0;
        for (int q=0;q<Sentence.length;q++){
            if(Sentence[q].contains(Keywords[i]) && Sentence[q].contains(Keywords[j])){
                count++;
            }
        }
        matrix[i][j] = count;
        matrix[j][i] = count;        
    }
}
```

This will output your example matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes to your program:

```
if (Keywords[i].contains(Sentence[q]))
```

this condition checks whether a sentence is contained in a keyword. You want to check the opposite.

```
matrix[i][q] = count++;
```

Why do you use this? You want to set the value of the cell to 1, if you find a match. Simply set the value to 1 instead of using a complicated expression that doesn't even work:

```
matrix[i][q] = 1;
```

In general:
Whatever IDE you use should provide a debugger. Learn to use it; there's no way to avoid this anyways, if you want to write working code on a larger scale.